# Jquery cookie - toggle box

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, toggle

I need to remember the state of clicked box (if its shown or hidden). I'm using cookies plugin for this.

When I click at `#clickable h3` I want to hide or reveal `#clickable p`... and I need to keep it hidden/revealed after F5 (so it will remember it's state).

On initial load that box must be hidden, but if no Javascript is present, it will be always revealed.
Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    /* On load show/hide box depending on cookie */
    if($.cookie('click_cookie') == true){
        $.cookie('click_cookie', true);
        $("#clickable p").show();
    } else {
        $.cookie('click_cookie', false);
        $("#clickable p").hide();
    }

    /* When clicked */
    $("#clickable h3").click(function(){
        /* Animate box */
        $("#clickable p").animate({
            height: "toggle",
            opacity: "toggle"
        })
        /* Toggle cookie */
        if($.cookie('click_cookie') == true){
            $.cookie('click_cookie', false);
        } else {
            $.cookie('click_cookie', true);
        }
    });
});
```

The problem is that it doesn't work as intended. The box is always hidden after F5. `$.cookie('click_cookie') == true` will never evaluate, so it will be always hidden.

Comment: try  `$.cookie('click_cookie', 1);` and see if the cookie is set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. $.cookie returns and sets strings:

```
$(function(){
  /* On load show/hide box depending on cookie */
  $("#clickable p").toggle($.cookie('click_cookie') == "true");

  /* When clicked */
  $("#clickable h3").click(function(){
    /* Animate box */
    $("#clickable p").animate({
        height: "toggle",
        opacity: "toggle"
    })
    /* Toggle cookie */
    var show = $.cookie('click_cookie') =="true"; // also false if no cookie at all
    $.cookie('click_cookie',show?"false":"true");
  });
});
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. The behaviour is still the same - after F5 it's hidden.

Comment: Is cookie loaded? Any errors in console? I updated the script to be more clear

Comment: My fault, your code works as expected, problem was, that I tested it on local... Chrome does not allow local cookies. But your code definitely works, thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't think any browser does.

Comment: And your string idea was perfectly right, it works with "false" "true" but not with false true...